# How to get contents of container view to scroll in sync with parent tableview in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, uicontainerview

I have a table view controller which contains a view and below that, 2 container views. Each container view containing individual tableviews with some data (see diagram).

A segment control is used to switch between which of the container views are visible.

The content within the container views extend beyond the height of the main screen.

Currently the parent tableview controller is scrolling independently to the table views within the container views which is expected.

How can I sync the container views and parent tableview to scroll together?

Current hierarchy is shown in the diagram below:

[Current view controller hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfd4s.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually having this kind of UX/UI is not a good idea. I personally hate this UX.
But to answer your question, you could observe for the `contentOffset` property of both child tableViews using KVO and update the parent tableView's contentOffset accordingly by doing the appropriate calculations.

*Btw, you could use a regular UIViewController and UIScrollView as a containerView instead of the UITableViewController*

---

The ideal approach for me is having a SINGLE tableView, and loading all the content dynamically. F.e. you could have the segment control (and all static data) in the tableViewHeaderView, and depending on which tab is selected you could update the content of the tableView accordingly by switching the array of the first tab's datasource to the second tab's, and vice-versa.
Even if the UI of the cells differs for both tabs, you could dequeue two different cells depending on the selected tab.

Comment: Curious to know, do you mean the layout of UI is not a good idea with segment control switching views or are you talking about the synced scrolling? I'm actually experimenting different options since I don't like the way this works either. If I were to use your recommendation of a regular UIViewController and UIScrollView as container, wouldn't I have the same issue of not being able to scroll the top section and container (tableview inside) together?

Comment: The segment controls are always welcome! I was about putting one scrollable view into another scrollable view... 

Having a regular ViewController wouldn't solve your issue of-course, but using TableView as a container doesn't make any sense, as you don't use any benefit which provides TableView at the end..

Comment: That's useful thanks. I know you've answered the question already don't have to answer the next part but if you don't mind me asking your advice. If I wanted to have a user profile with profile image at the top, then segment control right below to switch between two different sections of the profile. Each section needs a table and several custom cell types. What would be the best practice to set that up?

Comment: I think I already answered that question. Just refresh the page :D

Comment: I see, that’s a great approach actually. If on one selection of the segment there need to be several sections and many types of custom cells in the table view whereas on the other side of the segment there is only one type of recurring cell. Is there enough flex to allow for that?

Comment: Yes. The TableView provides all the necessary method to do that

Comment: That's awesome, I have it working now - thank you very much!

Comment: U r welcome! Then you could mark my answer as accepted ;)